# Why is my Pac-man character is not moving? (Turtle)

Tags: python, python-turtle

First problem: i was making a pacman game and when i run the code it outputs an error, the error in the title. I am using Turtle module to build this game.

Second problem: Also, My Pac-man character yellow circle is not moving when i press the WASD keys. I will appreciate every help.

```
import turtle

# screen

wn=turtle.Turtle()
wn.width(800)
wn.height(600)
wn.color(0, 0, 0)

# pacman

pac=turtle.Turtle()
pac.size(2)
pac.shape("circle")
pac.color("yellow")
pac.goto(1, 1)

def display_screen(screen, wn):
    wn.screen_width = wn.width
    wn.screen_height = wn.height
    wn.color = wn.color(0, 0, 0)

def pacman_move_up(self, pac):
    self.move_up = pac.onkey("W")

def pacman_move_down(self, pac):
    self.move_down = pac.onkey("S")

def pacman_move_left(self, pac):
    self.move_left = pac.onkey("A")

def pacman_move_right(self, pac):
    self.move_right = pac.onkey("D")

# i need help with the next code. (current file name: spec.py)
```

Comment: You wrote "it outputs an error, the error in the title" but there is no error message in the title. More importantly, your code is broken. You define a bunch of functions that take a `self` argument but that is only valid for class methods. Another problem is that `wn=turtle.Turtle()` should be `wn = turtle.getscreen()`. Please take some time to read a tutorial (https://realpython.com/beginners-guide-python-turtle/) and the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: the error was `AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'height'`

Comment: Please ask one question per question.